# How can I test an if condition in functional component with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

The method isAuthorized() is a global method.

```js
import { isAuthorized } from 'xxx';

const Comp = (props) => {
  const shouldShow = isAuthorized('abcd');
 

  return (
    { shouldShow ? <A /> : <B /> }
  );
}
```

I am trying to pass shouldshow as props like this:

```js
const props = {
  shouldshow: true
};

const wrapper = getShallowWrapper(props);
expect(wrapper.find('A').exists()).toBe(true);
```

It doesn't work.
Searched a lot but didn't find a solution.

Also tried the ways below, didn't work.

```js
const mockIsAuthorized = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'isAuthorized');
```

```js
const mockIsAuthorized = wrapper.instance().isAuthorized;
mockIsAuthorized = jest.fn();
```

Does anyone know how to unit test this if-condition? Or say, how to mock the function inside the functional component?

Thanks

Comment: try mocking isAuthorized function

Comment: @lissettdm I tried, cannot mock the it successfully inside the the functional component. Tried jest.spyOn, wrapper.instance(), both way didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `jest.mock('xxx')`?

Comment: [how mock modules in jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)